# Can a Database <databasename> statement and a revoke statement cause a deadlock in Terdata

Tags: deadlock, teradata

We have been observing a deadlock on 2 sessions, one which is executing Database ; and the other session has revoke statements.  Can this be possible?

Thanks,
Piyush

Comment: I would' expect that, but if you observed it... Of course both `DATABASE` and `REVOKE` access system tables, you should check Explain for details.

Comment: Hi Dieter,
Just to give you a brief idea of the issue, there are multiple sessions of statement type Database <Databasename> and set query band, which are failing due to a deadlock observed at a particular time of the day. At this time there is an automated revoke script that runs at our end, which generates revoke statements for restricting unnecessary accesses, and eventually runs them one by one.

Comment: I am able to observe through the dumplocklog entries that the sessions were indeed blocked by the revoke script and vice versa. But I am not able to get any deadlock from the dumplocklog entries. 

I have also observed that there revoke session is blocked by ITSELF (according to the dumplocklog entries!!), and sometimes by session id 0

The resources due to which blocks are observed are:
1. DBC.sessiontbl
2. DBC.ACCESSRIGHTS
3, DBC.ROLEGRANTS

Comment: Can you tell me:
1. What can be the issue here?
2. How to handle such deadlock issues, which do not show a clear deadlock in the viewpoint or Dumplocklog entries? Do we have some document for the same?

This will really help us a lot, Thanks...

Comment: There's no obvious reason why those statements could result in a deadlock. Both DATABASE and SET QUERY_BAND only update DBC.SessionTbl using the UPI, but this table is not touched by REVOKE. I assume that each REVOKE is a single transaction? You probably need to open an incident with Teradata's customer support...